# python - in-place string reversal

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am attempting to reverse a string in-place. For instance "hello world" should result in "olleh dlrow". This example would be no problem, as there is only one space between both words.

But some examples got 3 spaces in a row in the middle of the string, which makes it difficult for me to figure out a good approach as its not enough to use `split()`, `slicing` & `.join()`.

Comment: Have a look into this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python

Comment: `str = 'hello word'` `print(str[::-1])` = `dlrow olleh`